# Cannot attach Images in Overleaf template

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I am using a LaTeX template for my thesis which is provided by my university. When I try to insert an image, I am getting the following error. I have used `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the template. I have attached
both code for inserting images and error below.

I was told to attach MWE for the question. So I have attached the link from where anyone can download the template that I am working with. From the below link, download 'LaTeX template for Bachelor-/Master-Thesis' zip file. That is the template that is giving me problem.

Link:
https://agrosy.informatik.uni-kl.de/en/teaching/templates

Code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{bilder/my_photo.png}
    \label{fig:trial image}
\end{figure}
```

The error (complete error image is alos attached):

```
LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in bilder/my_photo.png (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.202 ...degraphics[scale=.4]{bilder/my_photo.png}
                                                  
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

[image]

I am new to using LaTeX. Can someone please tell me if I am doing anyting wrong here?
If the information provided here is not sufficient to solve the error, let me know in the comments. I will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Usually, the file extension does not have to be specified for `\includegraphics`. Check if the path and file name are correct.

Comment: you have not shown the error message, just the paragraph after the message referencing the manuals

Comment: Made changes in the original question. Now I think the error is visible.

Comment: check in the overleaf menu which engine you use. You need pdflatex, lualatex or xelatex (not latex) for png files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks this worked for png images. I also a few jpg and tif images. Is there a LaTeX which is compatible with all formats of images or do I need to change the image file extension?

Comment: jpg should work, but there is no tif support. Convert them first (and converting does not mean to change only the extension!).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, understood. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.